# How to get pointer of storyboard UITabBarController in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I am using the storyboard to create my app. At the root of my app is a UITabBarController. How do I access my `tabBarController` from inside my Application Delegate? I manage to successfully implement the manipulations from inside one of my UIViewControllers. But I want to move the code to my app delegate. How might I accomplish this? I thought I could just drag and drop from storyboard to my app delegate and get something like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

but that does not seem to be an option presently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bringing that code to AppDelegate does not seem like a good idea but if you wanted to do it you could add a weak property in the AppDelegate and set that property from your UITabBarController.

In ApplicationDelegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyTabBarController *tabController;
```

In MyTabBarController awakeFromNib method:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.tabController = self;
```